# How to print the remaining set of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, math, arraylist

Say there is a set **U = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}** and I created a C++ program and I, using some logic printed the numbers { **1, 3, 6, 7, 9} (let's call it set A)**, so the remaining numbers are **{2, 4, 5, 8, 1} (let's call it set B)**

and **U = A + B**

Is there a direct way to print out set B numbers **(B = U - A)**? (Without actually reversing the logic from which I printed numbers of Set A)

Like if I printed even numbers, then the remaining are odd numbers and I can easily code to display odd numbers. But I am asking if there is another "direct" way of doing it?

Similarly, if I printed all prime numbers from 1-100 then I can kind of reverse the logic and print the numbers which were NOT printed (here, which were NOT prime), but I am NOT asking for that, I am asking is there a direct way to print the remaining set of numbers?

PS: I only know basic C++ and I have NOT yet started DSA (Data Structures and Algorithms) still any level answers are welcome, I will try hard to interpret it :)

Comment: [`std::set_difference`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)?

Comment: @Evg Sir, I didn't quite understand that reference article, I am a beginner.

Comment: In your example, `U` corresponds to the ordered list of natural numbers: `1 2 3 4 ... n-1 n`. Is it always the case. If yes, simpler methods exist.

Comment: @Damien No it was just an example to make it clearer what I was asking. I just want to print remaining set of numbers, like non-prime numbers if I printed prime before (without reversing the logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you hear "find the missing elements" or "find the duplicate elements" type problem, you should immediately think "hash table".  Do an internet search for Hash Table, but the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) has the basics.

`std::unordered_map` and `std::unordered_set` are collection classes in C++ that are traditionally based on hash tables.

Given a set U:

```
unordered_set<int> U = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
```

And a set A that is a subset of U:

```
unordered_set<int> A = { 1,3,5,7,9 };
```

Then `B = U - A` can be computed as

```
unordered_set<int> B;
for (int u  : U)               // for each item u in set U
{
    if (A.find(u) == A.end())  // if u is not in "A"
    {
        B.insert(u);           // add it to "B".
    }
}

for (int b : B)
{
    cout << b << endl;
}
```

If you need the output to be sorted, change the declaration of `B` from `std::unordered_set` to just `std::set`.

Comment: @shelby what are the header files required?

Comment: `#include <unodered_set>` and `#include <set>`